# Method onFinish of class CountDownTimer

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have a problem with the method onFinish (), I want that when the countdown is complete will call a function that changes my screen information, but instead of calling once called constantly.

This is the code of the method onFinish ():

```
@Override
            public void onFinish() 
            {        
                if(numPreg+1<opcElegida)
                {
                    Log.i("","numPreg: "+numPreg);
                    todo.get(numPreg-1).setRespD("");
                    timer.onTick(45000);
                    displayListView();
                }
                else
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Test.this, Soluciones.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
```

and this is the function code that refresh the screen:

```
private void displayListView() 
    {
        timer.onTick(45000);
        numPreg ++;

        String aux= Integer.toString(numPreg)+"/"+opcElegida;

        totalResp=4;
        preguntaEnunc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pregunta);
        preguntaEnunc.setText(todo.get(numPreg-1).getPreg());

        ordenPreg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.llevo);
        ordenPreg.setText(aux);

        arraydirResp.clear();   
        TemaRescatado temaGen = new TemaRescatado("C",todo.get(numPreg-1).getRespA(),1,false);
        arraydirResp.add(temaGen);
        temaGen = new TemaRescatado("C",todo.get(numPreg-1).getRespB(),2,false);
        arraydirResp.add(temaGen);
        temaGen = new TemaRescatado("C",todo.get(numPreg-1).getRespD(),3,false);
        arraydirResp.add(temaGen);
        temaGen = new TemaRescatado("C",todo.get(numPreg-1).getRespD(),4,false);
        arraydirResp.add(temaGen);

        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapterPreg(this,R.layout.item_gen, arraydirResp);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewPreg);
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
```

can anyone help me? thank you very much

Comment: I'm not getting how you use the timer? You should not call `onTick()` manually. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: @Droidman so if you should not call onTick () manually as you make the timer start again? using timer.start ()?

Comment: i use timer.start() and the problem disappeared

Comment: yep, this is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially user a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), but then you would have to deal with 'running stuff in the UiThread'...but your can still use the [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html), like this use it like this:

```
new CountDownTimer(TIME, TIME) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     //IGNORE IT
    }

    public void onFinish() {
       callYourMethodHere();
    }
}.start();
```